# Git: changes not made is visible when I do `git diff`

Tags: git

Here's what it shows when I do `git diff`:

[image]

...though I did not change it all. How can take this "change" out?

EDIT:

This I was able to fix on Sublime Text, while I couldn't fix on Atom. Might be Atom issue.

Comment: Could be a whitespace change. If you want to remove the change, just check the file out (note you will also revert any other unstaged changes in doing so).

Comment: I can't, because there are some edits in the file. Checked whitespace, no, it's not. (

Comment: So stage the other changes (`git add -p`) *then* check the file out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably changed whitespaces in that particular line. It may now be using spaces instead of tabs, for instance. One solution is to just revert back to spaces (if it is now tabs) and see if the diff goes away. But the more generic approach for selectively removing a portion of a diff in a file that you intend to commit is `git checkout -p` which interactively lets you revert your changes for different chunks of the file. Alternatively, you can use `git add -p` and decide which portions of diffs you want to commit from a given file,